# Calculating Probabilities with the PDF

Tags: statistics

I have that the PDF
$$f(x) = \frac{33 - 4x}{75} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{2 \le x \le 7\right\}}$$

I need to be able to find $P(x > 4)$ & $P(x > 5.5|x > 4)$ but I don't know how. I thought I would need the CDF, e.g. $$P(x > 4) = 1 - P(x \le 4) = 1 - CDF$$ but I don't have the CDF so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you check the definition of a PDF, say on WP?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to confirm what I was saying. I could only find defining probabilities between certain values.

Comment: Obviously you did not read very carefully: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties

Comment: If given the PDF, then $$P(X>4) = \int_4^{+\infty} f(x)\ dx$$

Comment: Wouldn't that only be true if I was looking for $P(X \ge 4)$? Besides, you can't solve that integral.

Comment: In this case, $P(X=4) = 0$, so its the same thing. And you can solve that integral -- just take it.

Comment: This would be not true if you had a summation (i.e. discrete data), but with continuous it is fine to include the lower limit.

Comment: Take $7$ as the upper limit, because $\int_7^{\infty} f(x) \, dx=0$

Comment: Also $P(X>5.5|X>4)=\frac{P(X>5.5 \ \cap \  X>4)}{P(X>4)}=\frac{P(X>5.5)}{P(X>4)}$

Comment: Third hint: The result is 4/11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of your function, with support in $[2,7]$, it's simply
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_x(s) \;\mathrm{d}s = \int_2^x \frac{33-4s}{75}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{2 \leq s \leq 7\right\}} \;\mathrm{d}s =
\begin{cases}
0 & \qquad x<2 \\
-\dfrac{1}{75} (x-2) (2 x-29) &\qquad 2 \leq 7\\
1 & \qquad x>7
\end{cases}\tag{I}
$$
So, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=F_X(x)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X>x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq x).$ Thus, part one is
$$\mathbb{P}(X >4) = 1-F_X(4)=\frac{11}{25}\tag{II}$$

For part 2, we recall 2 things into one big formula:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A|B)= \frac{\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)},\tag{III}
$$
Where the events $A:X>5.5$ and $B:X>4$. Then, we write:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X>5.5|X>4)
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>5.5) + \mathbb{P}(X>4)-\mathbb{P}(X>5.5 \cup X>4)}{\mathbb{P}(X>4)}, \tag{IV}\\
&= \frac{(1-F_X(5.5)) + (1-F_X(4)) - (1-F_X(4))}{(1-F_X(4))}, \tag{V}\\
&= \frac{1-F_X(5.5)}{1-F_X(4)}=\frac{4/25}{11/25} =\frac{4}{11}. \tag{VI}\\
\end{align}

Note that the event $A\cup B:X>5.5 \cup X>4$ is given by $X>4$.

Comment: Why calculate $P(X>5.5\cup X>4)$ when you can calculate $P(X>5.5\cap X>4)$?

Comment: To make it more illustrative, since the poster does not seem to have a strong (or any) basis in proba.

Comment: $P(X>5.5)=1-0.84=0.16=\frac{4}{25}$ Please control your result.

Comment: Thank you, @callculus . I used 5 instead of 5.5 in the calculation.

Comment: This can happen everybody every time. The answer itself is nice. +1

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. You are of course correct about my background, I am a pure math guy on my first stats course with a very bad professor. Even his TA said he doesn't know what he is talking about half the time.